# Best aproximation to an numerical solution using two aproximated functions

Tags: functions, special-functions, curves

I want to find the best aproximation to a numerical solution. For that I want to use two aproximated functions (that I already know). If I plot them I see that one of them underestimates the original solution and the other  overestimates it.

It would be nice to combine this two "bad" approximations to find a better one.This way I think the error will be more or less compesated, but I don't know how I could do this properly.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Did you try a linear combination of the two aproximated functions (trying to adjust the weighting factor(s))  ? May be, you could give more details in order we see what could be suggested.

Comment: I didn't, so I will try. Thank you, Claude. By the way, I wrote it wrong. I want to get the approximation to the numerical solution of a first order differential equation (I wrote analytical solution). My first approximated function is of the form: $$g(x)=\alpha~~ {}_2F_1(a,b,c,x)+\beta~~ \int_{x_0}^{x}f(u){}_2F_1(a,b,c,u)du,~~\alpha,\beta=constants$$ and the second one is same but replacing the hypergeometric functions 2F_1 by the Laplace approximation. The first one underestimates the numerical solution, the last one, overestimates it.

Comment: My approximated solution, according to your idea, would be: $$s(x)=A~g(x)+B~\tilde{g}(x)~~~A,B=constants$$ I will try to do a fit with Mathematica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to know in what sense you want the best approximations, and whether you are looking only for linear combinations of the functions or not. As an example, you can take a linear combination $\tilde{f} = \gamma g + \delta h$ of the 2 approximations $g$ and $h$, choose a set of grid points, use the values of the numerical solution and $\tilde{f}$ at these grid points and calculate simple OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) estimates for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ to get a "best" discrete approximation in $L^2$.

Comment: Hello, CottonTensor, and thanks for your answer. I just have the curve corresponding to the numerical solution and my two functions. With these ingredients I want to be able to give a mathematical expression which best approximates to the numerical curve. So I'm not looking specifically for a linear combination of the two, but for a method which do the approximation better (minimizing the error). Is there any other way to work with these two functions?

Comment: Why does my suggestion not work? Once you find $\gamma$ and $\delta$, the approximation $\tilde{f}$ will be a better approximation than either $g$ or $h$, atleast at these grid points in the sense that the $L^2$ norm of the difference between your approximator and the numerical solution will be minimum.

Once you allow for non-linear combinations, there is just too many possibilities and there is no guarantee if any one will be better than the other. I'm also not aware of any generic method to generate better non-linear combinations without knowledge of the problem at hand.

Comment: I didn't mean that doesn't work. In fact, that's what I'm doing. I just commented that it's not mandatory that it has to be a linear combination. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there an option to implement this in Mathematica? I've just started to use it. By the moment I have a table with the values of the numerical $\tilde{f}$ at the grid points. How can I perform OLS then?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html

Here your $x$ is the 2x1 vector $[\gamma \; \; \delta]^T $, the $m$ matrix is the values of the approximations $g$ and $h$ at all the grid points i.e. $i^{th}$ row of $m$ is a 1x2 vector $[g(x_i) \; \; h(x_i)]$ and your $b$ is a column vector with $b_i = \tilde{f}(x_i) $. You will obtain the least squares estimate for the co-efficients

Comment: In the above comment $b$ contains the numerical values, not $\tilde{f}(x)$. I'm sorry for the mistake. Also, you might find this helpful.

http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/eda/FittingDataToLinearModelsByLeast-SquaresTechniques.html